# How to tell where a shared library is loaded in process address space?

Tags: android, c++, c, gdb, shared-libraries

I'm trying to debug a shared library to which I have the source code and debugging symbols for using gdb.
I do not have debugging symbols or code for the process that actually uses this shared library (I compile it myself, so I can have everything, but the resulting binary is stripped, to simulate a situation where I don't have the code).
The process prints the address for target function foo I'm trying to debug, to test that gdb knows the right location for symbols from the shared library. foo exists the my shared library.
My method of printing it is adding the following line to the binary that uses my shared library:

```
printf("%p\n", foo)
```

...and to add complexity, this is an Android system I'm debugging remotely.

The scenario I'm trying follows:
On target:

```
root@phone:/proc/23806 # gdbserver --attach :5555 23806                        
Attached; pid = 23806
Listening on port 5555
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
```

On host:

```
[build@build-machine shared]$ /home/build/shared/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.7/bin/arm-eabi-gdb
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3.1-gg2
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-android".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
(gdb) target remote :5555
Remote debugging using :5555
0xb6f17fa0 in ?? ()
(gdb) add-symbol-file out/target/product/armv7-a-neon/symbols/system/lib/libShared.so 
The address where out/target/product/armv7-a-neon/symbols/system/lib/libShared.so has been loaded is missing
```

Now I know what I need - the relocated .text section of this shared library in the process address space, but I have no idea how to find it.
I tried /proc/23806/smaps:

```
root@phone:/proc/23806 # cat maps  | grep Shared                                  
b6ea0000-b6edb000 r-xp 00000000 b3:10 3337       /system/lib/libShared.so
b6edc000-b6ede000 r--p 0003b000 b3:10 3337       /system/lib/libShared.so
b6ede000-b6edf000 rw-p 0003d000 b3:10 3337       /system/lib/libShared.so
```

And the .text section is located at 0x0003ff00 in the .so file:

```
[build@build-machine shared]$ objdump -h out/target/product/armv7-a-neon/symbols/system/lib/libShared.so | grep text
  7 .text         0002835c  00003ff0  00003ff0  00003ff0  2**3
```

So now I'm supposed to have the address where my shared library is located:
0xb6ea0000+0x00003ff0=0xb6ea3ff0 (where the library is loaded+.text offset from the beginning)
So I did:

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file out/target/product/armv7-a-neon/symbols/system/lib/libShared.so 0xb6ea3ff0
add symbol table from file "out/target/product/armv7-a-neon/symbols/system/lib/libShared.so" at 
.text_addr = 0xb6ea3ff0
(y or n) y
```

Now I tried setting a breakpoint for the foo function from my shared library:

```
(gdb) b F10
Breakpoint 1 at 0xb6ea41de: file frameworks/native/test/shared/src/shared, line 122.
```

And it doesn't match the value from my binary which was 0xb6ea4217 (printed on the screen).

It appears I did not provide the correct memory location for the shared library, but I'm clueless why.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after scratching my head on this one on and off for some time now, I finally discovered what went wrong.

The solution came from a different angle, I recently had to debug some code I had partial sources for, so I did hybrid source/assembly debugging and noticed that when debugging the source, things start to skew - I can't use next instruction as it will crash - but when I debug instructions everything works great!

I then added and compiled the following short code in the AOSP tree:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int first,second;
    first=1;
    second=2;
    return first+second;
}
```

And, as expected, it would not debug properly (assembly debugging works, source debugging does not).

Then I noticed argc has been OPTIMIZED OUT!

So... what really happened here was a compiler optimization that prevents debugging of source code as there is no 1:1 relations between the generated instructions and the actual source. Since I left the default build flags in the hands of the AOSP build script, I got these weird debugging issues...

Thanks @EmpyloyedRussian for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to run `(gdb) x/10i 0xb6ea41de` and `(gdb) x/10i 0xb6ea4217`.

I am guessing that either GDB, or your program prints the address of the `PLT` entry, and not the real address of `foo`.

P.S. Your method of calling `add-symbol-file` appears to be correct.

Comment: Not the same assembly instructions... I am really stumped by this one, it works flawlessly on Linux machines.  
One more thing, on a second glance I notice that the shared library is mapped to a non continuous memory location, while in my Linux tests it was always continuous...

Comment: @IshayPeled "Not the same assembly" --  of course they are not the same -- how could they -- they refer to different addresses. But one of them *probably* looks like a PLT stub. You should update your question with the `x/10i` results.

Comment: The addresses are not the same, this has nothing to do with PLT as it works flawlessly on Linux machines (same gdb server and gdb versions).

Why should there be any difference between the Linux version and the Android one?

The only difference between the two is the non-continuous memory mapping which I bet is the cause for this mess, but I can't figure out WHY it is mapped differently and HOW to calculate the symbol address otherwise.