# How can an argument be different in the caller and the callee?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I'm debugging a program and ran across something I've never seen before. Below is an excerpt from `gdb`.

```
1236            size = init_text_buffer(fn);
(gdb) p fn
$13 = 0x7fff1cd22d80 "-"
(gdb) s
init_text_buffer (fn=0xd00 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xd00>)
    at editors/vi.c:720
720 {
```

The function `init_text_buffer` is called with a `char` pointer with the value `0x7fff78136bd0`. As I step into the function the argument suddently has a different value.

What are possible causes of this? I'm not asking you to debug my code (I didn't include any so how could you?), I just need a pointer in the right  direction. This thing has left me with no clues as to what to look for at all.

Comment: Show all relevant code! My crystal ball broke yesterday.

Comment: OK, something corrupted that parameter, maybe it's your code?  ^^^^^^

Comment: @Olaf But none of my code was executed in between. What code is relevant?

Comment: It's **your** code, so why ask me?

Comment: Also, are you debugging a build with all optimization off?  You should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go into hybrid assembly mode (Ctrl+x 2) and do stepi to examine which instructions are actually being performed. I had this recently - in my case it was an optimization that the C code of course didn't reveal. In your case, it could reveal a memory overrun.

Worth a shot.

Comment: Have an upvote for mentioning optimization.  All kinds of weird stuff happens with high optimization and debuggers.   I frequently see object instance pointer parameters with null values on method entry; they turn into valid values after a few lines have been executed:)

Comment: Not to mention crazy stuff when doing step by step... See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844867/how-to-tell-where-a-shared-library-is-loaded-in-process-address-space that's what I was referring to. I struggled with this on and off for two weeks...

Comment: ^^ lol....................

Comment: I stepped through the instructions as you suggested. I couldn't reproduce the same message, but I found a bug and fixing lead to the error going away. It can't have been the cause though, since that code was executed inside a function called by `init_text_buffer`.